# How can I get the links of the apps from a certain developer, till now i have scrapped the web objects but unable to get the actual links?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to extract the links of all application from a particular developer present on the playstore.

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver. common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=5305197572942248936")
l1 = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ULeU3b')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close to the solution.
Inside elements you located there are `a` elements containing the links.
All you need here is to wait for all those elements to become visible, get the list of those elements, iterate over the list and extract the links.
The following cod works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=5305197572942248936"
driver.get(url)

links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ULeU3b a")))
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

The result is:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tatamotors.eguruibcrm
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.T1.Primarun
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tata.skoolman
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttl.tatafleetman
```